# "Order by" results from SQLITE query not ordered

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

I am working on a webshop-project. I am trying to get sorted results based on parameter values from a sqlite database. I am trying to sort products based on "select" values.

In my app.js

```
app.get('/sortMaleProducts', function(request, response){

    var sortValues = request.query.sortValue;

    if(sortValues == 'priceASC')
    {
        sortValues = ["man", "price", "ASC"];
    }
    else if(sortValues == 'priceDESC')
    {
        sortValues = ["man", "price", "DESC"];
    }

    db.sortMaleProducts(sortValues, function(error, clothes){
        if(error){

            console.log("Error: "+ error);
        }
        else{

            console.log(clothes)
            const model = {

                clothes
            }

            response.render("man.hbs", model)
        }
    })
})
```

In my db.js

```
exports.sortMaleProducts = function(sortValues, callback){

    const query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE gender = ? Order by ?, ?'

    db.all(query, sortValues, function(error, clothes){

        console.log(clothes);
        callback(error, clothes);
    })
```

If I hardcode the query like:

```
const query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE gender = 'man' Order by price ASC'
```

Then it works....But I want to use user inputs so I can reuse code..

Comment: Query parameters cannot be used to specify database schema objects or SQL keywords.  They can only be used to pass data values.  The parameter in the WHERE clause is correct, but the other two in the ORDER  BY are not correct.  There is not a direct solution to this problem other than dynamically building the SQL string using other techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by a column, that column name has to appear directly in the query. What you're doing sorts the results by the strings `'price'` and `'ASC'`, which are the same for every row so any order of results is sorted.

You can't use column names as parameters anywhere else in a query either, like in the columns to return or in a `WHERE`. They have to be present when the statement is prepared by compiling it into sqlite's internal bytecode, which happens before any parameter binding or the execution of the query.